# Is there a way to use arrayformula with match/index in google script? Or at least get it to autofill the entire column? Scripts are an option

Tags: google-sheets, indexing, match, array-formulas, lookup-tables

I have the following formula:  =ArrayFormula(INDEX(Items!F2:F,MATCH(C2,Items!E2:E,0)))
I would like to extend it such that the entire C column runs the same formula for values. Please help. If a script is necessary to achieve this, I'd like to explore that option too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, Items!E2:F, 2, 0)))
```

Comment: Just as I feared. Vlookup... I had seen other answers saying as much but I hoped there'd be a new solution, us being in 2021 and all. Thank you very much. I'm curious though, if I wanted to concat with the value of another VLookup, almost exactly like the one you've given, how would that work? [=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, Items!E2:F, 2, 0)) & IFNA(VLOOKUP(C2:C, Items!E2:F, 2, 0)))] This gives an error.

Comment: @EkeEke what says the error. can you share a copy of your sheet?

Comment: I got it to work. The error was asking to add more rows because I had put it in the wrong row when I was testing. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

### Use Apps Script!

Sheet functions (formulae) work great (especially if you are a master like player0), but I find it much easier to work within Apps Script for anything much more complicated than a simple INDEX MATCH. If you are willing to learn some JavaScript, I highly recommend learning some.

#### Custom Functions

You can write custom sheet functions in Apps Script that you can call with the traditional `=FUNCTION()` from a cell.

The way it works is that you write a function in Apps Script that returns a two dimensional array corresponding to the area that it needs to fill.

For example, if wanted a function to fill a 2 x 2 block with `1`, you would need to make your function return:

```
[[1,1],[1,1]]
```

Or you can write it like this:

```
[
[1, 1],
[1, 1]
]
```

#### Implementing Index Match

There are many ways you can implement it, here is an example.

The example spreadsheet has 2 tabs, "Ledger" and "Items".

[image]

[image]

The goal of the function that follows is to get the costs of the items from the "Items" tab.

```js
function ledgerIndexMatch(){
  // Initializing the location of data
  let ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  let ledger = ss.getSheetByName("Ledger");
  let source = ss.getSheetByName("Items");
  let ledgerRange = ledger.getDataRange();
  let sourceRange = source.getDataRange();

  // Getting the values into a 2D array
  let ledgerValues = ledgerRange.getValues();
  let sourceValues = sourceRange.getValues();

  // Discarding the first row (headers)
  ledgerValues.shift();
  sourceValues.shift();

  // Initializing the output array
  let output = [];

  // This is where the INDEX MATCH happens

  // For each row in ledger
  ledgerValues.forEach(ledgerRow => {
    // Get the second column (index 1)
    let item = ledgerRow[1];

    // Initialize the column
    let value = [];

    // For each row in the source
    sourceValues.some(sourceRow => {
      // Check if the item is there
      if (item == sourceRow[0]) {
        // if so, add to value
        value.push(sourceRow[1]);
        // stop looking for values
        return true
      // if not matched, keep looking
      } else return false
    })

    // Add the found value (or blank if not found)
    // to the output array.
    output.push(value);
  })

  return output;
}
```

Which can be used like this:

[image]

Whats nice about Apps Script is that you can customize it to your heart's content. In this example, the function automatically detects the height of the respective tables, so you don't need to fiddle around with ranges.

You might want to extend this function with arguments so that its more flexible. Or you could just have a few versions of it for different operations, if you don't have too many. Or refactor it... its up to you.

#### References

- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions)
- [Tutorials](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/tutorials)
- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer. I am fairly comfortable with javascript so I was hoping for an appscript workaround that would extend the index/match; mostly because I had just learnt about it and was too attached to the idea of using it. Your answer is more elegant though, thanks for that.